Lift embedding of a non-orientable hypersurface to embedding of its orientation double cover
Let $M$ be a closed orientable manifold. Let $S\to M$ be a closed embedded non-orientable hypersurface. Then can I lift $S\to M$ to an embedding $\tilde S \to \tilde M$, where $\tilde S$ is the orientation double cover of $S$, and $\tilde M$ is a double cover of $M$?
I am thinking of cutting $M$ along $S$ and gluing two copies of $M\setminus S$ along the boundary $\tilde S$ will give me the double cover $\tilde M$. Is this correct?

Yes, or take the double cover of $M$ corresponding to the mod 2 Poincare dual of $[S]$.

Just wanted to point out that the analogous result is not true for arbitrary codimension, e.g. $\mathbb{RP}^2 \to S^4$.

@MichaelAlbanese Thanks! I was also wondering about this
